# Illustrator graphics for word doc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, microsoft-word

I need to place graphics from Illustrator into word. Every time I save as png or wmf the size is smaller than the actual size in Illustrator. Does anyone know what to do to get the word placement to appear the same size as original?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say smaller, by how much? Screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

There are different things to consider:

First the dimensions of the file as you save it. As you are not copy-pasting from AI into Word (which you might consider as well, sometimes these mechanics work pretty nicely) you will have a copy of your exported graphics on the Desktop.

So, if you are sure the file is the correct size and resolution, you need to check your Word. When you paste an image into Word you can resize the image with different options. You can manually scale it or set the size using a dialog. Then, when saving your Word file, you need to make sure that the Word settings are correct to not let Word scale-down the image resolution. Check this under Settings -> Advanced -> Image size and quality.

That are all factors I can think of.